# Allow Laravel ManyToMany migration to have multiple of the same combination

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, many-to-many, database-migration

I am running into a problem with the ManyToMany relationship in Laravel.

I have table A and table B, with a pivot table to connect them. When I try to attach A and B with some custom pivot data, it works just fine. But as soon as I try to make another connection between A and B with some different pivot data it either gives me an error that the tables are already connected or it just gives the tables the same ID, which messes up my whole website.

It seems like the `$table->increments('id');` does not do anything, because even if I remove it, the table still has an id field which seems to be a combination of A and B IDs.

I want to be able to have lots of connections between A and B with custom/unique pivot data.

Table A named *bounties* has the following schema builder

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->boolean('enable');
$table->char('name');
$table->char('slug');
$table->timestamps();
```

And Table B named *users* has the following

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->boolean('enable');
$table->char('name');
$table->char('slug');
$table->timestamps();
```

The connection pivot named *bounty_user* table is setup like this

```
$table->increments('id');

$table->json('user_data')->nullable();

$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->unsignedInteger('bounty_id');
$table->foreign('bounty_id')->references('id')->on('bounties')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->timestamps();
```

My *user* model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;


    public function bounties()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Bounty')
            ->withPivot('user_data', 'state')->using('App\BountyPivotCasting')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And the bounty model

```
class Bounty extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'name'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withPivot('user_data', 'state')->using('App\BountyPivotCasting')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your table models make sure you have this

Bountie Model

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'bounty_user');
}
```

User Model

```
public function bountie()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Bountie::class, 'bounty_user');
}
```

Then use **sync** to attach and detach
EX: `$user->bountie()->sync(bountie_id)`

Comment: Yes I have it setup like that, heres the user model one

    `return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
        ->withPivot('user_data')->using('App\BountyPivotCasting')
     ->withTimestamps();`

Comment: As you can see here https://i.imgur.com/XllFEOF.png the records has the exact same ID, I assume because the combinations of the game and name are the same, but they have different pivot data. The image is data tables from the pivot between.

Comment: There is no errors, they items are just not unique because they have the same ID for some reason. Which makes it so that if I try to change an item, it changes all of the items with the same ID. They all need to have a unique ID so that I can attach the same models to each other multiple times with unique pivot data. But the ID's are not unique.

Comment: Can you provide me ur model and controller

Comment: Yes, added to original post.

Comment: try to use this public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'bounty_user');
}

Comment: If you look I already do that, with some extra pivot data and timestamps.

Comment: I just need the ID in the pivot table to be unique even if the user is connected to the same bounty multiple times.